# Two parameters on a function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, dom-events

I'm trying to make a button onclick event jump to another function if input fields is empty. The function inside the if-statement should have two parameter(one array, one string variable). The function is looping trough all input elements and check if they have a value, if not then add text to a variable that later on is assign to a p-element with `.innerHTML`.

It worked with only the input parameter, but when I tried to add msg, it stopped working. Maybe it's a simple reason, but I am new to this.

How can I make this work?

```js
var assignment = document.getElementById("assignment");
var inputs = assignment.getElementsByTagName('input');
var btnCreate = document.getElementById("submit");
var message = document.getElementById("message");
        
var msg = "";

btnCreate.onclick = function() {

  if (inputs[0].value === "" ||  inputs[1].value === "" || inputs[2].value === "") {
    emptyInputs(inputs,msg);
  }

  message.innerHTML = msg; 

}

function emptyInputs(input,text) {

  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

    if (input[i].value === "") {

      if(!text) {
        missing();
      }

      text += "- " + input[i].name + "<br />";  

    } 

    function missing() {
      text = "<strong>Please type in:</strong> <br />";
    }
    
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="assignment"> 

  <h1>Add new user</h1>

  <form id="newUser">

    <div class="inputGroup">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
    </div>

    <div class="inputGroup">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/> 
    </div>

    <div class="inputGroup">
      <label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password2Confirm" name="confirmPassword"/> 
    </div>

    <button id="submit" type="button">Opprett</button>

  </form>

  <p id="message"></p>
      
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close to solving your problem. The only thing is, JavaScript doesn't have ouput params.

When you pass an object or array you can modify the content and those changes will be reflect in your calling method. But this doesn't work for strings. Whatever the value of the string is when you use it as a param to call your method, it will still be the value no matter what your method does to it.

```js
var
  array = ['hello'],
  object = { hello: true },
  string = 'hello';
  
function modifyArray(inputArray) {
  inputArray.push('bye');
}

function modifyObject(inputObject) {
  inputObject.bye = true;
}

function modifyString(inputString) {
  inputString += ', bye';
}

modifyArray(array);
modifyObject(object);
modifyString(string);

// This will print hello and bye
console.log('Content of array after calling method: ', array);
// This will print hello and bye
console.log('Content of object after calling method: ', object);
// This will just print hello
console.log('Content of string after calling method: ', string);
```

To solve your problem, create a `text` string inside the method that builds the error message and return that string as the method result.

```js
var assignment = document.getElementById("assignment");
var inputs = assignment.getElementsByTagName('input');
var btnCreate = document.getElementById("submit");
var message = document.getElementById("message");
       

btnCreate.onclick = function() {
  var
    // Initialize the error message to an empty string.
    msg = '';
    
  // Check if either of the inputs is empty...
  if (inputs[0].value === "" ||  inputs[1].value === "" || inputs[2].value === "") {
    // ... and get a custom message prompting the user to fill in the empty data.
    msg = emptyInputs(inputs);
  }
  
  // Display the error message, or clear it when msg is an empty string.
  message.innerHTML = msg; 
}


function emptyInputs(input) {
  // Initialize the error text.
  var 
    missingPrompt = "<strong>Please type in:</strong> <br />",
    text = '';

  // Iterate over the provided input elements.
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  
    // Check if the value of the current input is an empty string...
    if (input[i].value === "") {
      // ... check if the error text is still empty...
      if(text === '') {
        // ... and if it is start with a default message.
        text = missingPrompt;
      }

      // ... add the field name to the error message.
      text += "- " + input[i].name + "<br />";  
    } 
  }
  
  // Return the error message.
  return text;
}
```

```html
<section id="assignment"> 

  <h1>Add new user</h1>

  <form id="newUser">

    <div class="inputGroup">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
    </div>

    <div class="inputGroup">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/> 
    </div>

    <div class="inputGroup">
      <label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password2Confirm" name="confirmPassword"/> 
    </div>

    <button id="submit" type="button">Opprett</button>

  </form>

  <p id="message"></p>
      
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code without msg parameter, and it's working just fine.

```js
var assignment = document.getElementById("assignment");
var inputs = assignment.getElementsByTagName('input');
var btnCreate = document.getElementById("submit");
var message = document.getElementById("message");

var msg = "";

btnCreate.onclick = function() {

  msg = "";

  if (inputs[0].value === "" ||  inputs[1].value === "" || inputs[2].value === "") {

    emptyInputs(inputs);

  }

  message.innerHTML = msg; 

}

function emptyInputs(input) {

  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

    if (input[i].value === "") {

      if(!msg) {
        missing();
      }

      msg += "- " + input[i].name + "<br />";  

    } 

    function missing() {
      msg = "<strong>Please type in:</strong> <br />";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="assignment"> 

  <h1>Add new user</h1>

  <form id="newUser">

    <div class="inputGroup">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
    </div>

    <div class="inputGroup">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/> 
    </div>

    <div class="inputGroup">
      <label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password2Confirm" name="confirmPassword"/> 
    </div>

    <button id="submit" type="button">Opprett</button>

  </form>

  <p id="message"></p>
      
</section>
```

Comment: Creating a global variable works but it is not really a very elegant solution. I've added an answer with a different approach, one that doesn't require global variables.